# example of $H_1(X,\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ is not isomorphic to $H_1(X,\mathbb{Z})\bigotimes \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-module

Tags: modules, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Let $X$ be topological space.
I'm looking for a example

$H_1(X,\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ is not isomorphic to $H_1(X,\mathbb{Z})\bigotimes       
\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

I think if X is connected space, $Tor^1(H_0(X, \mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{Z})$ is trivial, so thanks to universal coefficient theorem, above two module are isom.

Comment: Do you really mean to be using cohomology? If so, then $\mathbb{R}P^2$ is an example, since $H^1(\mathbb{R}P^2; \mathbb{Z})=0$ but $H^1(\mathbb{R}P^2; \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I mean homology. If there are no torsion parts in homology, the two modules are isom, I guess. Right?

Comment: If you mean homology, please change $H^1$ to $H_1$ throughout. The superscript means cohomology. Since $H_0$ is always torsion-free, then the Tor term will be zero, to answer your main question.